# I am having problems with VDB volumes that intersect, it just leaves random patches that look like the volumes aren't there

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

So I did a smoke simulation in Houdini, exported i and imported it into blend and I need to place it six times around 1 point but for some reason the places the volumes intesect have random patches that look like the volumes weren't there. rended it with cycles, expamle:[image: Example of the roblem, visible on top and on the left][image: How the volumes intersect]